# Entity Framework Core 7, one to many causes mutiple cascade paths, never had a problem in older version. What am I doing wrong now?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am rewriting an old .NET Core/EF Core 2 web app in .NET / EF Core 7.

I have the following two entities which, as far as I remember, worked fine in the old app but now I get an error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ReleaseDates_Sections_SectionID' on table 'ReleaseDates' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints

I am not sure if I have always been doing something wrong in the entities and fixed it somewhere else I can't see it or if something has changed over the years and I am now doing it completely wrong.

```
public class Section
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(15)")]
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }

    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public int? LogoFileID { get; set; }
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ReleaseDate> ReleaseDates { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
    public SiteFile LogoFile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
    public SectionType Type { get; set; }
}

public class SectionType
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ReleaseDate
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Released { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int SectionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionID")]
    public Section Section { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
    public SectionType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Am I supposed to be fixing this via FluentAPI's `Cascade` command or is there something I am screwing up in the entities that I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : This model don't work in .NET Core 2.1 and EF Core 2.1 with SQL Server. I tested and reproduced the same error.

---

The model has multiple cascade path :

```
Section -> ReleaseDate
Section -> SectionType -> ReleaseDate
```

And [SQL Sever don't allow this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-1785-database-engine-erro). To understand, see this data :

```
SectionA -> ReleaseDateA
         -> SectionTypeA -> ReleaseDateA
```

When the `SectionA` is removed, by cascading this remove also `ReleaseDateA` and `SectionTypeA` . And remove `SectionTypeA`, by cascading this remove again `ReleaseDateA`... `ReleaseDateA` is removed two times.

But this seems legit, just need to `ReleaseDateA` one time. Other DBMS like MySQL manage this. Then why not SQL Server?

I don't know and found no official information about this. Just found this :

> [SQL Server - Why can't we have multiple cascade paths?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100493/why-cant-we-have-multiple-cascade-paths)
>
> ...so instead of fixing it, the implementation avoids it by preventing the definition of duplicate cascade paths. It's clearly a short-cut...

SQL Server has this constraint and we need to live with. A solution is to avoid multiple cascade path. In your case, you can :

```cs
public class ReleaseDate
{
    ...
    public int? TypeID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
    public SectionType? Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So the solution is to allow nulls? How do I enforce that the typeID MUST be in the DB and MUST be a valid PK in the type table?

Comment: I finally got some time to dig into NULL FK in SQL and understand it much better now. It was not something I was not aware of. Thanks for this information.